# set<pair<K, V> > with greater functor by default

Tags: c++, stl

I have `map <string,int>` where I have to sort map on value. 
I have dumped map elements in a `set<pair<K, V> >` where I got all the element in less than order as `set` is constructed with a less functor. So is there any way I insert element in a `set` with `greater` functor.

Comment: You do know what the template arguments to [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) are, or what arguments you can provide to the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), `std::set` is defined as:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

To sort in a different order, we simply have to provide a different `Compare`, in this case:

```
std::set<std::pair<K,V>, std::greater<std::pair<K,V> > mySet;
```

But if you already have a `std::map` with the objects in them, [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) also allows for a different comparator:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

If you wanted to sort in decreasing order by `K`, rather than copy all your elements into a `set`, you could have just started with:

```
std::map<K, V, std::greater<K> > myDecreasingOrderedMap;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)'s 2nd template parameter with `std::greater<Key>` instead of the default `std::less<Key>`.

```
std::set<Foo, std::greater<Foo>> s;
```

Here's a working example:

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::set<int> a{4,2,8,6,4};
  std::set<int, std::greater<int>> b(a.begin(), a.end());

  for (auto i : a) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << '\n';

  for (auto i : b) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 8 
8 6 4 2
```

Comment: As of C++14, you can use `std::greater<>` instead.